# PUG rendering or HTML for performance?

Tags: html, express, pug

I was playing today with Jetbrains Webstorm on an express project I have. It gives me the option to compile pug files into html so I was wondering? Isn't it better to compile the pug files into HTML and serve those from express for performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you do that you're not understanding the dynamic nature of pug.

Pug dynamically generates the HTML each time it is called, so if you have a template that shows the user's name inside a `div` tag based on the results of a database query the same pug template can be used for all queries/users.   It's also in-memory and very fast.

If you compile into HTML then somehow you'll have to parse the HTML files and do token substitution before sending the HTML to the client.

If your application is truly static with zero dynamic content then you're better off using pug-loader and webpack to generate HTML using a script instead of an IDE like VS Code or WebStorm.